# Align two subfigures vertically

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I'm writing a LaTeX document where I want two or three QR codes vertically aligned with caption on each. Unfortunately the first QR code is always one line lower than the other QR codes and I can't figure out why.

I have a workaround with negative `\vspace`, but I'm hoping to find the error or something neater.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[]{qrcode}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}    
        \centering        
        \qrcode[]{Text1}
       \caption*{Text1}
    \end{subfigure}
        \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}[ht]{0.2\textwidth}
        \centering    
        \qrcode[]{Text2}
        \caption*{Text2}
    \end{subfigure}      

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Thank you for your example. You don't need to load `caption` when you use `subcaption`. Latter one does `\RequirePackage{caption}`.

Comment: Thanks, the example was not minimal, I removed the \usepackage{caption}, the problem with horizontal alignment however persists.

Comment: Sure, dont worry. Your example was totally fine. Just a fineness on the use of the `caption` package bundle I was pointing to... I posted an answer that solves the issue.

Comment: @Richard I removed the `[solved]` part of the title, as the way we mark questions solved on this site is to accept answers. See [this question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/30280) for how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\subcaptionbox`es as they get vertically aligned automatically:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Text1}{\qrcode{Text1}}
  \qquad
  \subcaptionbox{Text2}{\qrcode{Text2}}   
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop]

Comment: Perfect, even shorter than my initial solution, thank you very much.

Comment: @Richard, the usual way to say thanks is to upvote and accept the answer (of course the one which helped most :)